# Can't access object URL via website, even after making object/bucket public

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, access-denied

**Scenario:** I'm hosting a website from an S3 bucket. One of my webpages (http://sebavalenzuela.com/music-students.html) has links to objects in the same S3 bucket. These links make use of the "Object URL" you can find on the object's 'Overview' page in the console. When I try to click on these links on my webpage to access the object, I get an access denied XML:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>827B2C82F76FD989</RequestId>
<HostId>
XZCOVs2ZmsL/2eGqR/rYwMYQdFjbupwg2vJKk3d2KU+sOB118Viev+EJsfe51m+uphXpEBN9Mec=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Any help would be appreciated! How can I make these objects public, so people visiting my website can access them via these URLs?

These are all the things I've done to try and make this bucket/objects public:

- In the "Block public access" menu, everything is OFF
- I've gone to individual objects and clicked "Make Public"
- This is my bucket's policy:

[image]

- This is my CORS policy:
  [image]

Comment: It sounds like you have done everything correctly. If you take one of the URLs that is giving `Access Denied`, and paste that URL into your web browser, does it work correctly? If you copy the URL that works from the S3 management console and compare it to the one that doesn't work, what is the difference? (Please note that clicking the LINK in the console gives a different URL than clicking OPEN in the console.)

Comment: I made it work! turns out I had capitalized a directory's name and left it that way in the URL path... I didn't think URLs were case sensitive! Thank you again, John.